# Не срабатывает find() в IE 8

Tags: jquery, javascript, internet-explorer

Собственно есть код, где мы подгружаем xml файл, затем его парсим. Но строчку

```
$("#manifest_"+current_i).find('organization>item').each(function(){
```

IE просто перескакивает, будто таких элементов вообще нет. На других браузерах (хром, фаерфокс, опера) все работает. Что может быть не так?

```
$("#manifest_" + i).load(i + '/imsmanifest.xml', function () {
    $("#manifest_" + current_i).find('organization>item').each(function () {
        xmlParse(this);
        $("#content").append(mylist);
        mylist = '';
    });
});
```

**Дополнено.**

Хм... видимо это не find, т.к. изменив конструкцию на

```
$("#manifest_"+current_i+' organization>item').each(function(){
```

тоже ничего не происходит.

```
alert($(this).find('organization').html());
```

говорит там пусто, что не верно.

Comment: IE ? Не удивительно!

Answer (score 2):

Проверьте content-type ответа, который парсится. Сделать это можно так:

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function(e, x) {
    alert(x.getResponseHeader("Content-Type"));
});
```

IE на это чувствителен. Скорее всего у Вас не "text/xml".

Comment: спасибо, помогло!